# Endless activity scheme

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, native, lifecycle

In my app there is the ability to have an endless activity stack. The scenario is that you start on one user's page which has a list of people that are "friends" of that user. You can then click on a friend to go to their page, which looks just like the previous one, where you can then click on another friend to go to their page, and so on...

The big problem I am facing is an endless native heap. I believe I am adding to this heap everytime a view is inflated. After a few iterations of this, I am getting OOM errors consistently, so I have to find some kind of solution. The trick is, I want to maintain the last few activities at minimum for navigating some history.

The best I can come up with is monitor the activity stack, and then start finishing activities when it reaches a certain point. Does that sound like a solid approach, or even further can anyone point me to an implementation of that or another approach?

Thanks

edit:

The stack is very simple. Click on a listrow (a friend), go to their page. This is using a normal startActivity call with an intent to the same page you are on, and an intent extra with the user id that will then call the database or a remote api call to get the user's data.

Also, to follow up about Dalvik vs Native, I am routinely checking the meminfo dump during my navigation. I am keeping the dalvik heap as small as possible, cleaning out resources in onStop. The native heap grows much quicker. I have no hard references to bitmaps anywhere, but quite a few drawables on the screen from inflations. Would these drawables lead to android killing my activity eventually? As best I can tell they just lead to OOM without any of my activities being destroyed preventatively.

If I could manually destroy my activities instead of just stopping them (as Android claims to do when low on memory), and keep the destroyed activity on the stack with the state saved, that would be ideal.

edit again:

another key is that these activities will have other activities mixed in with them e.g.

user -> user -> activity a -> user -> activity b -> user

so that is why I want to make use of the built in stack, so I know when I have to go to a user activity and when I don't.

Comment: how exactly do you implement your "stack" of user pages?

Answer (score 1):

how about making this activity `singleInstance`, intercept KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, build own back button stack for this activity

i made some example here:

http://esilo.pl/selvin/endlessactivity.zip

Comment: a good idea (and an upvote for that), however my needs are a bit more complex. Something i neglected to mention is that these activities will have other activities mixed in with them, editing above to reflect that

Comment: download new version(from the same source) ... i forgot to add `setIntent(intent);` in `public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)` (whithout it if you change orientation you'll lost backstack)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the OOM problem you are experiencing is related to the number of Activities you have open. Android should be destroying any old activities in the background as memory pressure increases. These Activities will then just be re-created when the user returns back through the task stack.

Have you used a tool like MAT (memory analyzer tool) to examine what you have allocated during the runtime of your application. I suspect that you may have a memory leak, or that yo may have to be smarter in your memory allocations.

Comment: I have used MAT and have been pretty careful about releasing resources onStop too. Watching the meminfo dump as I navigate deeper, both native and dalvik go up. Will the system kill an activity because of a native heap problem too? I thought that was seperate...

Comment: Well I would expect both native and dalvik to go up until a GC is run. If most of your memory is allocated native side, I think you are correct in your assumption that Dalvik will not react to that. It sounds like you are doing most work on the native side. Are you sure your cleanup is working properly, because onStop should be called for an activity when you move to the next one in the stack.

Comment: My cleanup is working, but it might not be thorough enough. I clear out the lists and list recycle bins to get rid of the rows, but the other views are intact, meaning everything outside of my list retains its drawables (buttons, backgrounds, header images, etc). I suspect this is why the native heap just keeps going up, everytime it inflates these drawables they just sit there. So the way I see it I either have to kill all of my views onstop (which seems like overkill) or regulate the size of my activity stack. If i could see what was in my native heap I would be more confident.

Comment: Yea, It might be more helpful to others if you post more about what you are doing natively VS in Dalvik inside your question since NDK is really outside my expertise. I do know that you shouldn't try to persist drawables between activities unless you are very careful about how you unbind them from your activity. See android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html talking about this very issue.